# Why can't I see my (SSIS) integration services packages when I connect to the integration services server?

Tags: ssis

I am using sql server 2019.

I have connected to the integration services via sql mangement studio.

In there I can see following folder structure:

-Running Packages
-Stored Packages

Within Stored Packages there is:
-File system
-MSDB

None of these folders contain the SSIS packages that I have deployed. **Why is that?**

Where as if I connect to the database engine, then under Integration services catalog, SSISDB, there are folders that contain my packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Package Deployment Model (legacy, only option for 2005/2008/2008R2) allows one to store *packages* on the file system, the Package Store (also file system but in a specific location), or the `msdb` database.

SSMS has a Connect type option for Integration Services. This allows you to see the Running Packages/Stored Packages folders and the subsequent packages in the file system.

The Project Deployment Model (new 2012+) allows one to store *projects* (Packages, Project parameters, project connection managers, manifest file), in the form of an .ispac file, into the `SSISDB`.

The management interface for this in SSMS is the Integration Services node under the Connect option of Database. There you will have a hierarchy of
Folder/Project/Packages.

You do not see any packages listed in the Integration Services connection type because you have no custom packages deployed  (you should have the ~8 System Data Collector Packages there as they're shipped with the database).